# Send Template as Envelop Docusign Java

Tags: java, scala, docusignapi

I have create Template on my docusign account. I want to use this template to send to recipients in my application using Docusign-Java-Client Program.

Right now I am reading .pdf from my local machine but i don't want to use local document, i want to use Template on docusign.

How can i read that Template in java?
i will do same in scala.

Code in Scala :

```
val loginInfo = authApi.login()

        val loginAccounts: java.util.List[LoginAccount] = loginInfo.getLoginAccounts
        val SignTest1File = "/TermsnConditions.pdf"

        var fileBytes: Array[Byte] = null

        try {
          val currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")

          val path = Paths.get(currentDir + SignTest1File)
          fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path)
        } catch {
          case ioExcp: IOException =>
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ioExcp)

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/SdkUnitTests.java SDK, and it has a sample method RequestSignatureFromTemplate() to request signature using templates.

Comment: I have used above java SDK with my Integratory key,clientId and private key but it is not working while with given key it is working.